# Meaning of "backpropagate through Gaussian distributions"?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation

I just started reading about GAN theory properly for the first time and I have a question about a comment in the [original GAN paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf).

On page two there's a paragraph that states the following:

> ... had developed more general stochastic backpropagation rules,
>   allowing one to backpropagate through Gaussian distributions with
>   finite variance, and to backpropagate to the covariance parameter as
>   well as the mean.

Can anyone explain what backpropagating through a distribution means? In other words, what's the concrete meaning of this?

Comment: Actually, this paragraph is not in the (arxiv) version of the paper you linked. It is in the NIPS version: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The quoted paragraph (actually appearing in the [NIPS version](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf) of GAN paper) is dealing with variational autoencoders (VAE). Particularly, it refers to their *reparametrization trick*, which allows efficient computation of gradients of expected values over distributions parametrized by the differentiated parameters.

How exactly this reparametrization works is described nicely in: [How does the reparameterization trick for VAEs work and why is it important?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important)

Another great, easy to understand explanation is in the blog post [The reparametrization trick](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/04/29/reparameterization/) by Gregory Gundersen.