# A technical question about the reparametrisation trick

Tags: neural-networks, expected-value, variational-bayes

I was reading [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important) which enlightened me about the technicalities of the reparametrisation trick, but I only get the intuition of this equivalent transform and I'm not sure why it is true:
$$_[x^2]=_[(+)^2]$$

The intuition is clear - we have introduced another random variable which produces our previous random variable but our $ \epsilon $ is sampled from a new random variable, which has different distribution.

The definitions are:
$$ q_{\theta}(x) = \mathcal{N}(\theta,1) $$
$$ x = \theta + \epsilon $$
$$ \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

My attempt:
I think p in this context means $ p(\epsilon) = \mathcal{N}(0,1) $

So then the exercise is to prove:

$$ E_q [ x^2] = \int_{X} x^2 q_{\theta}(x) dx = \int_{\eta} (\theta + \epsilon)^2 p(\epsilon) d\epsilon $$

I assume it is possible then to argue that for  a given $ x_0  = \theta + \epsilon_0 $ the equation will only agree if we make a shift, but for me this is still too intuitive. Could we express this more rigorously? (feel free to throw Measure Theory at me if needed)

Comment: There's no exercise to be done, the equality holds above basically by definition since this is just a change of variables from x to $\epsilon$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a change of variable. The expectation operator uses the density of the random variable(s) inside the expression. However, if you just look from a calculus perspective:
$$x=\theta+\epsilon\rightarrow dx=d\epsilon, \ \ \epsilon=x-\theta$$
$$q_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x-\theta)^2}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\right)=p(\epsilon)$$
And, the limits of $x$, i.e. $(-\infty,\infty)$ are shifted by $\theta$, but, since infinity, they're the same. Or, you could leave them as in your notation, $X\rightarrow\eta$. Then, it follows that $E_q[x^2]=E_p[(x+\theta)^2]$

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what i was looking at. The interpretation with calculus combined with the change of variable for probability densities makes me feel more comfortable about this.